# Download file in background using FileTransfer in ionic,phonegap

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have packaged my AngularJS/javascript application with phonegap/Cordova for Android, and later plan to do this for iOS/BlackBerry. In this project, I implemented the FileTransfer.download function from the phonegap API to download a file from the server. The function is working successfully, but it blocks me from navigating to other pages within the app until the download is complete.

Maybe I'm missing something in the documentation: what's the best way to get FileTransfer.download to work in the background so that I can freely navigate page to page? Is it possible without resorting to device-specific code?

Comment: i think that plugin doesnt support background process

Comment: so what is better solution? plz suggest me

Comment: make your own native file transfer, in another word, make your own plugin

Answer (score 1):

Using FileTransfer plugin is not really necessary to download files in phonegap. You can do it directly in javascript, and it shouldn't block your UI (despite JS is mono-thread, the thread shouldn't be collapsed by an async download).

I suggest you using [**downgularJS**](https://github.com/kaikcreator/downgularJS) - https://github.com/kaikcreator/downgularJS

This AngularJS module can be easily integrated with ionic, it uses cordova file API and **don't require file-transfer plugin**.  You can create several queues to download files, and perform any operation after file downloads, and it's pretty well documented.